# How do you know if an assembly instruction stores in a new variable or not?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Let's say the value 4 is stored in register "%eax" (and the C variable for it is "varX") and the value 3 is stored in register %edx (and the C variable for it is "varY").
If the assembly code is "subl %edx, %eax", then in C how do I know if the instruction translates to

```
int varZ = varX - varY;
```

or

```
int varX = varX - varY;
```

If the second case is correct, then what assembly instruction would cause the first case to be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that instruction in isolation, you probably can't know with any certainty whether the target is `varX`, `varZ`, or something else entirely.

Something like `int varZ = varX - varY;` might compile to a sequence like this (using Intel rather than AT&T syntax):

```
mov eax, varX
sub eax, varY
mov varZ, eax
```

Likewise, for `varX = varX - varY;`, you might get something like this:

```
mov eax, varX
sub eax, varY
mov varX, eax
```

The `sub` just gives the difference of `varX` and `varY`. If you store the result to `varX`, then it's giving `varX = ...`, but if you store the result to `varZ`, then it's giving `varZ = ...`.

It's also possible that it's enregistered `varX` in `eax`, in which case the `sub` by itself might be equivalent to `varX = varX - varyY;`, but without seeing how the value is used, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: varX's value is stored in %eax and varY is stored in %edx. 

On a related note, if I use the movl command and move a value from a memory address into a register, then is a new variable created at that time?

Comment: @ShadowCrossZero: if the content of `eax` is used as `varX` after the `sub`, then yes, the `sub` is equivalent to `varX = VarX - varY;`.

Comment: If optimizations is also used, it may not even have a variable representation outside a register.